# Setting up spritesheet position as background of anchor tag on Reddit

Tags: css

So, we have this standings table on the sidebar which have the team's logo as a background appended to it's left. We managed to style it correctly but given the large number of teams and Reddit's limitations regarding number of images allowed, we were forced to switch to a sprite sheet. However, I am failing miserably at trying to set it up.

The sprite sheet is composed of several 45x45px logos but we're trying to set it on the sidebar at 22x22px. I tried resizing the background-image to the appropriate size (original size is 1440x90px but for 22x22px it would be 704x44px since the row with the max width has 32 logos) but never managed to get the right position within the spritesheet nor the right display).

This is the set of rules that accomplished what we are trying to do but with individual logo images, associated with the example:

```
.md a[href*="clubcode=BER"]
 {
    background-size: 22px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 25px;
    display: block;
    background-image: url(%%alba%%);
}
```

If you take a look at the [subreddit](https://old.reddit.com/r/Euroleague/new/), I've left this one on for reference (Alba Berlin).

Tried several approaches but ultimately failed with setting the desired dimensions.

```
.md a[href*="clubcode=BER"]
 {
    background-image: url(%%sheet%%);
    background-size: 704px 44px;
    background-position: 0 0;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 25px;
    display: block;
}
```

Setting the width and height here will cause the whole anchor to that size, not the background. Also messed around with the `:before` pseudo-element but it wouldn't display at all, presumably because the anchor might be filling the whole table cell.

Take into consideration that changing the DOM is not an option, it has to be done solely through CSS.

Spritesheet: https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/FcgEv48G-d1i-5z0msnd2z1CdlZS14QcQprQcFQVdqA.png

Comment: You can not apply this to the whole link, that is simply too wide - other icons next to the one you want to display, would show in the additional space. So, yes, this should be done using a pseudo element. If you have trouble figuring out the correct background-position values - then I would recommend to modify those live in the inspector in the browser dev tools, usually pretty easy to figure out the correct values that way.

Comment: @04FS I see but the problem with the pseudo element is that I'm not getting anything drawn up, so the positioning of the whole pseudo element is off and I have no idea what is causing this. anyway, I've updated the CSS stylesheet to so that there's a pseudo-element with the spritesheet as the background of the first element of the standings table (Alba Berlin). any chance you can take a look?

Comment: @04FS I figured it out after all. Thank you.